# Date Queries with MongoDB and Spring Data MongoDB

Tags: mysql, mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I wanted to search for the list of reservations where the reservation start-date and reservation end-date falls between a certain date ranges.

If I query it in MySQL it would be something like:

**MySQL:**

```
SELECT * FROM MotelReservations
WHERE motelId = 'ABC123' AND (
  (dateStart BETWEEN '2018-12-01 00:00:00' AND '2018-12-31 23:59:59') OR (dateEnd BETWEEN '2018-12-01 00:00:00' AND '2018-12-31 23:59:59')
)
```

But I am not sure what the equivalent of the query for mongodb would be.

**MongoDB:**

```
{
  "motelId": "ABC123",
  ???
}
```

Also, since I will be using Spring Data MongoDB specifically repository approach. I wanted to query it using JPA like style where I can just use `findAllBy...` method name. If it is not possible, I can settle with using `@Query` annotation. The problem is, I am not sure what the equivalent of the query in mongo-db.

**Spring Data MongoDB (Repository):**

In `MotelReservationDao` interface, search by method name `findAllBy...` or using query annotation

`findAllByMotelIdAnd...(String motelId, ...)`

```
@Query(???)
findAllReservationsThatFallsOnGivenDates
```

**Sample Mongo Document:**

```
{
    "reservedBy": "Mang Kanor" ,
    "id":  "b1a7ddd3-ddfd-4624-8e85-79b47fb19f99" ,
    "motelId":  "ABC123" ,
    "dateEnd":  "2018-11-20T10:00:00" ,
    "dateStart":  "2018-11-20T09:00:00" ,
    "summary":  "Enjoy the moment in room 123"
}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of one your MongoDB motel document ?

Comment: added a sample document :)

Answer (score 1):

### Equivalent query in MongoDb

MongoDb query that can be used to retrieve your sample document,

```
{$and: [
    {'motelId':{$eq:'ABC123'}},
    {$or: [
        {'dateStart':{$gte: '2018-11-01 00:00:00', $lte: '2018-12-31 23:59:59'}},
        {'dateEnd':{$gte: '2018-11-01 00:00:00', $lte: '2018-12-31 23:59:59'}}
    ]}
]}
```

Or with implicit `$and` operator:

```
{'motelId':{$eq:'ABC123'},
$or: [
    {'dateStart':{$gte: '2018-11-01 00:00:00', $lte: '2018-12-31 23:59:59'}},
    {'dateEnd':{$gte: '2018-11-01 00:00:00', $lte: '2018-12-31 23:59:59'}}
]}
```

### Equivalent query for Spring data mongo

I'm not sure you can create this complexe query using Spring Data method signature. But you can look at [this section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-creation) for further information.

### 1. Using @Query annotation

```
@Query("{'motelId':{$eq:?0},$or: [{'dateStart':{$gte:?1, $lte:?2}},{'dateEnd':{$gte: ?3, $lte:?4}}]}")
public List<MotelReservation> findReservationByDate(String motelId, Date from1, Date from2, Date to1, Date to2);
```

### 2. Using `MongoTemplate`

**MotelReservationDAO interface**

```
public interface MotelReservationDAO extends MongoRepository<MotelReservation, ObjectId>,
        CustomMotelReservationDAO {

}
```

**CustomMotelReservationDAO interface**

```
public interface CustomMotelReservationDAO {
  public List<MotelReservation> findReservationByDate(String motelId, Date from1, Date from2, Date to1, Date to2); 
}
```

**CustomMotelReservationDAOImpl class**

```
public class CustomMotelReservationDAOImpl implements CustomMotelReservationDAO {

    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @Override    
    public List<MotelReservation> findReservationByDate(String motelId, Date from1, Date from2, Date to1, Date to2){

      Query query = new Query(
        Criteria.where("montelId").is(motelId)
        .andOperator(
          Criteria.where("dateStart").gte(from1).lte(from2),
          Criteria.where("dateEnd").gte(to1).lte(to2)
        )
      );

     return mongoTemplate.find(query, MotelReservation.class)
}
```